# Fast way to slice an Eigen SparseMatrix

Tags: c++, sparse-matrix, eigen

In finite element analyses it is quite common to apply some prescribed condition(s) to a big sparse matrix and get a reduced one. This can be achieved easily in `MATLAB`, `SciPy` and `Julia`, for instance, in `MATLAB`

```
 a=sprand(10000,10000,0.2); % create a random sparse matrix; fill %20
 tic; c=a(1:2:4000,2:3:5000); toc % slice the matrix to get a reduced one
```

Assuming that one has a similar sparse matrix in `Eigen`, what is the most efficient way to slice an Eigen matrix. I don't care about a copy or a view, but the methodology needs to be able to cope up with non-contiguous slicing. The latter requirement makes the `Eigen block` operations useless in this regard.

I can think of two methodologies that I have tested:

1. Iterate over the columns and rows using for loops and assign the values to a second sparse matrix (I know this is a truly bad idea).
2. Create a dummy sparse matrix with zeros and ones and pre and post multiply it with the actual matrix `D*A*A.transpose()`

I always use `setFromTriplets` to create a sparse matrices in Eigen and I have been happy with the solvers and assembling of sparse matrices. However it seems that this slicing is the bottleneck in my code at the moment

The timing of MATLAB vs Eigen (using `-O3 -DNDEBUG -march=native`) is

```
 MATLAB:                  0.016 secs
 EIGEN LOOP INDEXING:     193 secs  
 EIGEN PRE-POST MUL:      13.7 secs
```

The other methodology that I do not know how to go about is to manipulate directly the [I,J,V] triplets `outerIndexPtr, innerIndexPtr, valuePtr`.

Here is a proof of concept code snippet

```
#include <Eigen/Core>
#include <Eigen/Sparse>

template<typename T>
using spmatrix = Eigen::SparseMatrix<T,Eigen::RowMajor>;



spmatrix<double> sprand(int rows, int cols, double sparsity) {
    std::default_random_engine gen;
    std::uniform_real_distribution<double> dist(0.0,1.0);
    int sparsity_ = sparsity*100;

    typedef Eigen::Triplet<double> T;
    std::vector<T> tripletList; tripletList.reserve(rows*cols);
    int counter = 0;
    for(int i=0;i<rows;++i) {
        for(int j=0;j<cols;++j) {
            if (counter % sparsity_ == 0) {
                auto v_ij=dist(gen);                         
                tripletList.push_back(T(i,j,v_ij));      
            }
            counter++;
        }
    }
    spmatrix<double> mat(rows,cols);
    mat.setFromTriplets(tripletList.begin(), tripletList.end()); 
    return mat;
}



int main() {
    int m=1000,n=10000;

    auto a = sprand(n,n,0.05);
    auto b = sprand(m,n,0.1);
    spmatrix<double> c;
    // this is efficient but definitely not the right way to do this
    // c = b*a*b.transpose();   // uncomment to check, much slower than block operation
    c = a.block(0,0,1000,1000); // very fast, Faster than MATLAB (I believe this is just a view)

    return 0; 
}
```

So Any pointers, in this direction would be useful.

Comment: Hi, this is the same problem I had here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45401725/select-armadillo-sub-matrix-with-non-contiguous-indices